# Redirect Vue-Router on error in props function

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router, vue-class-components

I have this route definition:

```
{name: "article", path: "/article/:id", component: Article, props: true}
```

And this component (I use Typescript and vue-class-component):

```
@Component({
    props: {
        id: Number
    }
})
class Article extends Vue {
    id: Number;
}
```

Of course, this give me this warn

```
[Vue warn]: Invalid prop: type check failed for prop "id". Expected Number, got String.
```

So i update my route definition with a props function

```
name: "article", 
path: "/article/:id", 
component: Article, 
props:(route:Route) => {
    const id = parseInt(route.params.id);

    if(isNaN(id))
        throw new Error("id param should be a number")

    return {id}
}
```

This works, but i don't find how to redirect user to a specific page if he gave me a "bad" value for id param ("/article/toto" for example)

router.onError seems don't works here

Navigation guards, where in can use next(error) can't modify params/props

Someone have any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

All of the values in URL params are of `type String`.

In Your component, setup a watch for this specific property

```
props : ["id"],
watch : {
    id(current,previous){
      var reg = /^\d+$/;
      if(reg.test(current)){
        console.log("its a number");
      }
      else{
        console.log("its not a number");
        this.$router.push("/error"); //HomeComponent or ErrorComponent
      }
    }
  }
```

Now as the watch is setup, you can check if your current value in prop is of type Number or String using Regex.

```
if currentValue is Number then 
    GoAhead
if currentValue is NAN then 
    Redirect to HomeComponent or ErrorComponent
```